# Getting MySQL columns to update from multiple select

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, foreach

I have following `ranks` table for user roles

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| rank   | areas        | intranet_view  | intranet_writer  | admin_users  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1      | 'AREA I'     | 1              | 0                | 0            |
| 2      | 'AREA VI'    | 1              | 1                | 0            |
| ...    | ...          | ...            | ...              | ...          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I used to update it like this

```php
// form for selecting allowed areas
echo "<select size=\"10\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"areas[]\" multiple>";
    $kysely = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM customer_areas");

    while($areas = $kysely->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $areaArray = explode(',',$result['areas']);
        echo "<option value=\"".$areas['customer_area_code']."\""; if(in_array($areas['customer_area_code'], $areaArray)){ echo " selected"; } echo ">".$areas['customer_area_name']."</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";

// and this form is for selecting allowed privileges
$kysely = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ranks");
$rights = $kysely->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($rights as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'rank' || $key == 'areas') {
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"checkbox\"><label><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$key."\" value=\"0\" /><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$key."\" value=\"1\""; if($result[$key] == '1'){ echo " checked"; } echo ">".mb_strtolower($key)."</label></div>";
    }
}

// following is the form action page
if (isset($_POST['areas'])) {
    $areas = implode(",", $_POST['areas']);
} else {
    $areas = "";
}

try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    $kysely = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ranks");
    $rights = $kysely->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $i = 0;
    $sql = "";

    foreach ($rights as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 'rank' || $key == 'areas') {
        } else {
            if ($i != 0) {
                $sql .= ", ";
            }

            $sql .= $key . " = '" . $_POST[$key] . "'";
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $kysely = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ranks SET areas = ?, $sql WHERE rank = ?");
    $kysely->execute(array($areas, $id));

    $pdo->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $pdo->rollback();
}
```

I'd like to know if there is some good way to have those privileges in multiple select, too. When I made this code, my intelligence was not enough for multiple select so I made checkboxes.

The problem is that I don't know how to put the column names to the multiple selection so that updating works properly. Do I need to add e.g. `name=\"option".[$key]."\"` or something. I don't have any idea about how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Have you tried something?

Comment: This sounds like an HTML question

Comment: @sayed, the problem is that I don't know how to put the column names to the multiple selection so that updating works properly. Do I need to add e.g. `name=\"option".[$key]."\"` or something. I don't have any idea about how to do this. @e4c5, HTML tag added

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can retrieve by name  `name=\"option".[$key]."\"` 
like

```
<?php 
   foreach($options $key => $value):       

      echo '<input type="checkbox" name="option['.$key.']" value="$vlaue">';

   endforeach;
?>
```

so it look something like this,

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[0]" value="some_value0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[1]" value="some_value1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[2]" value="some_value2">
```

Comment: As I wrote, I don't want any checkboxes.

Comment: Use column name as it is in database in multiple select box -- echo "<select size=\"10\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"customer_area_code[]\" multiple>";